# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode in the excel file path i.e xlrd.open_workbook

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have written a program that makes an excel sheet that takes data from multiple files and adds them to the excel sheet. I have to further edit this worksheet again.

Here, I am trying to open a closed excel workbook. I am using xlrd.open_workbook to do it.
It is giving an error:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode

```
##Wrote some code that works fine until I try to open the same excel 
workbook again###

workbook.close()

book = xlrd.open_workbook('path')

sheet=book.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
book_wt=copy(book)
sheet_wt=book_wt.get_sheet(0)
```

The error I get is:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Users/MakeFile.py", line 135, in <module>
book=xlrd.open_workbook('W:\\User\\Folder1\\MakeFile.xlsx')
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 416, in open_workbook
ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 800, in open_workbook_2007_xml
zflo = zf.open(component_names['xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error message.

Comment: @BoarGules This is the entire error. Thanks

Comment: Looks like a _damaged_ `xlsx` File. Could you open with Excel? Could you try with `openpyxl`?

Comment: Yes, it does open. Also, I tried with openpyxl. Same error. @stovfl

Comment: Please explain this `book_wt=copy(book)`, what are you doing here? Which `copy`?

Comment: Just copying the book to a workbook object so I can further modify it. I read it in the xlutils documentation. @stovfl

Comment: Sounds strange to me! Could you add the`openpyxl` Code and Traceback? Possible to get a Link to the `xlsx` File?